# Double connections in Germany going to USA do i need transit visa in EU

Tags: visas, transit, germany

I'm travelling from Kigali-Rwanda to Frankfurt-Germany and from Frankfurt DE to Munich - Germany to USA two transits in Germany is that need a transit visa? Or any kind of Visa for just to be inside the two airports? I'm Rwandan national with a USA B1/B2 visa

Comment: surely no one _flies_ from Frankfurt to Munich?

Comment: @njzk2 why not?  I've done it at least a half a dozen times, usually because of missing a connection.  Lufthansa has nearly hourly flights.

Comment: @njzk2 There's up to around a dozen flights a day between them, including multiple widebodies.  So yes, clearly people do fly that route (which makes sense - it's faster/easier than other options when connecting to another flight)

Comment: @njzk2: FRA and MUC are Lufthansa's main hubs, so they are really well connected. LH  has 10 flights/day each way (roughly every 1-2 hours). This is a perfectly normal routing If I were ONLY want to go from Frankfurt to Munich I would also consider the train but that depends mostly on the exact start and end location.

Comment: @phoog why not? because it's a ridiculous waste of the little left of our carbon budget, given that there are very good low-carbon alternatives

Comment: @njzk2 what surely _should be_ and what surely _is_ are two very different things.  When a passenger arrives in one airport too late to make a transatlantic connection, Lufthansa can get them to the other airport in a couple of hours to catch a flight to the same destination -- the scheduled flight time is just under an hour.  By train, it's four and a half hours plus at least a half hour transferring from the gate to the platform and back, plus time to re-clear airport security. Furthermore, smaller destinations like Kigali are typically served from only one hub.

Answer (score 2):

Frankfurt airport has a transit area like many other airports. If your outbound flight from Frankfurt was outside of Germany then you would not need to enter Germany through passport control. So this would be a visa-free transit.

However, this is not the case for you as you need to board a flight from Frankfurt to Munich. As this flight is inside Schengen area then **you need a German/Schengen visa to pass through German border first**. Then you can board your flight to Munich.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This makes sense!

Comment: @Jonas be careful: you need a regular Schengen "short stay" visa (type C), not an airport transit visa (type A).